# Equalent mysql regex for following python regex

Tags: mysql

python pattern => ^(?=.*\bABDUL\b)(?=.*\bHAI\b.*)(?=.*\bMANSOOR\b).*$
need equalent mysql pattern
can you please help me out ?

Comment: What string matches this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The regex in question is a quite strange way how to match simple words. It is not clear what is the expected input. Maybe, the input justifies this approach.

```
^(?=.\bABDUL\b)(?=.\bHAI\b.)(?=.\bMANSOOR\b).*$
```

Which means: At the beginning there must be any character which is not a part of a word, then ABDUL, a non word character, HAI, a non word character, MANSOOR, a non word character or the end of the string.

```
^[^[:alnum:]]ABDUL[^[:alnum:]]HAI[^[:alnum:]]MANSOOR([^[:alnum:]]?.*)?$
```

Which is: At the beginning, not a number or alphabet character (alphanumerical), ABDUL, one non-alphanumerical, HAI, one non-alphanumerical, MANSOOR one non-alphanumerical or the end of the string.

I did not test it and did not intended to make it 100% the same as the first one, but it should be close enough.

For anyone who would like to copy it to their code:

- Matching the first character is not very common and can be a bug in the original regexp.
- (?=...) is an "lookahead assertion" which does not consume any characters, the POSIX version does not have it, but for a simple string searching it may not be important.
- Both versions should match strings like `!ABDUL$HAI)MANSOOR` - make sure that this is what you want.

For someone who would like to understand the regular expressions I used
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html for mysql (POSIX syntax) and https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html for python (PCRE = Perl compatible syntax)